# How to accidentally delete all rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Someone wants to take a stab at explaining the mechanics of this... this little quirk of the query parser almost caused major damage for me today.

Create a test table with 100 rows, with 1-100.

```
create table test( JobID int primary key);

;with numbers as (
    select 1 as n
    union all
    select n + 1 as n 
    from numbers
    where n < 100
)
insert into test
select n from numbers
```

Create a temp table with integers 1-50 in it:

```
select jobid as number into #deletions
from test 
where jobid <= 50
```

Now do a delete using an `IN` clause but with the wrong column name in the inner query:

```
delete from test where JobID in (select JobID from #deletions)
```

That last delete statement, from appearances, gives the appearance of deleting 50 rows...
However, there is no `JobID` in `#deletions`, so it kind-of pulls that from the outer query and ends up, somehow, deleting all the rows in test.

My question is, how on earth is it interpreting that inner query... `#deletions` only has 50 rows, so how is it pulling all 100 id's from the outer table? This type of typo/mistake almost caused major damage to me today.

In my opinion, this should throw some kind of parsing/syntax error or some kind of ambiguity error.

Here's a <kbd>[`SQL Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/181fc/5)</kbd>

Comment: At least you will not do a query like this again :-) Never submit a `DELETE` or `UPDATE` without testing. Change `DELETE` to `SELECT *` and see what' returned.

Comment: There is no ambiguity here because JobID exists only on the outer `test` table.  You are right that scope is not obvious, which is why it's a good practice to make a habit of qualifying column names with the table name or alias in multi-table queries.

Comment: Whenever you are messing with UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE/INSERT, always wrap with BEGIN TRAN and ROLLBACK TRAN.  One of the single most important pieces of advice for production Ops guys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use table aliases, the logic would be clear.  You think you are writing:

```
delete from test
    where test.JobID in (select d.JobID from #deletions d);
```

That makes sense, but it would generate a syntax error because `JobId` does not exist in `#deletions`.  So, scoping rules of SQL go to the next level to find `JobId` and interpret the query as:

```
delete from test
    where test.JobID in (select test.JobID from #deletions d);
```

This will delete all non-NULL values of `JobId`.

The moral:  Always use qualified column names.

Comment: The logical error in what was a simple clean-up script was very hard to spot. Fortunately, it only removed data from an inconsequential table but I was a little bewildered for awhile until I spotted the issue. I will always use aliases from now on, or use a JOIN for the delete rather than an IN clause.